# Does a symmetric random walk converge almost surely?

Tags: martingales

Does a symmetric random walk in- one dimension- converge almost surely? Can we prove or disprove it by martingales?

Answer (score 1):

No, it diverges almost surely, in the sense that for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and all $M\in\mathbb N$ there is almost surely an $n_+\gt n$ such that $X_{n_+}\gt M$ and an $n_-\gt n$ such that $x_{n_-}\lt-M$.

Comment: What if step sizes form a conditionally convergent series? I don't think this is OP's question, but it made me wonder. (Maybe I should post another question.)

Comment: @alex: See [Byron's paper](http://www.stat.ualberta.ca/people/schmu/preprints/rhs.pdf) on the random harmonic series, and references therein.

Comment: Step sizes are by definition nonnegative: how could they form a conditionally convergent series?

Comment: @Robert: I think the idea was that the sum of the step sizes doesn't converge, so the sum of the signed steps isn't absolutely convergent but might be conditionally convergent with probability $1$, as in the case of the random harmonic series.